# Smartsearch with multiple search modules

Tags: smartsearch

I manage a website that uses Smartsearch.

There are 4 search areas and the two of them show the the results from the other part.

The two search areas are "book" and "magazine".

When I am in the book area, it also shows results from the magazine area.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please, provide an example. Probably you have to make a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you define "Search Filters" in the Smart Search component that linked to categories?

If there's an option for that then you might be able to create a Smart Search plug-in that checks at which part it is requested, and takes that into account when searching:

More info: https://docs.joomla.org/Category:Smart_Search